# Passing in default date for Bootstrap DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have a page with multiple input elements e.g.

```
<input data-default="2015-05-19 09:21:29" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker">
```

This is my jQuery:-

```
$('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({locale:'en-gb', defaultDate:$(this).data('default')});
```

The default date part is not working, is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heavily updated]. Seems to be a scope problem. `$(this)` refers to the initialization object, not the input being datetimepickered'

```
$('input.datetimepicker').each(function(i, e) {
    $(e).datetimepicker({
        locale:'en-gb', 
        defaultDate: $(e).data('default')
    });     
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/hdhdy6w2/** or http://jsfiddle.net/hdhdy6w2/1/ with two input boxes and different dates.

Comment: I checked that example, it's showing the current time and date, not the value from my data-default attribute. I don't think the $(this).data('default') is returning anything but I'm not sure why.

Comment: this works:-
`$('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale:'en-gb', 
        defaultDate: moment($(this).data('default'))
    }).after($(this).length);`
this doesn't:-
`$('input.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        locale:'en-gb', 
        defaultDate: moment($(this).data('default'))
    }).after($(this).data('default'));`

Comment: @marcovanbostin Silly, silly me - didnt looked at the dates, just if there were any output of the date format functions. It was too late at the evening :( Sorry for that.  See updated answer, cannot believe I starred my blind at the date format.

Comment: The `Date.parse` bit seems not to work but isn't required, the date picker will accept a string representing the date. You've fixed the problem though, it was an issue with `this` thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dateElement = $('input.datetimepicker');
var defaultDate = new Date(dateElement.data('default'))
dateElement.datetimepicker({
  locale:'en-gb', 
  defaultDate: defaultDate
});
```

Comment: Yes it works for multiple input elements. ` $('input.datetimepicker')` => all input tags with class 'datetimepicker' why use each?